# How to call ssh by subprocess module so that it uses SSH_ASKPASS variable

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I am writing a GUI which uses SSH commands. I tried to use the subprocess module to call ssh and set the SSH_ASKPASS environment variable so that my application can pop up a window asking for the SSH password. However I cannot make ssh read the password using the given SSH_ASKPASS command: it always prompts it in the terminal window, regardless how I set the DISPLAY, SSH_ASKPASS, TERM environment variables or how I pipe the standard input/output. How can I make sure that ssh is detached from the current TTY and use the given program to read password?

My test code was:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import subprocess

env = dict(os.environ)
env['DISPLAY'] = ':9999' # Fake value (trying in OS X and Windows)
del env['TERM']
env['SSH_ASKPASS'] = '/opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass'

p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-T', '-v', 'user@myhost.com'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    env=env
)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: SSH will always prompt you in the subprocess that called it, so what you need to do is tell `Popen()` to send the password by using `p.stdin.write()` or just simplify the whole damn thing and use something for SSH interaction that has already been written for you such as Paramiko.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to send the password using p.stdin.write() and p.communicate(), buth ssh still used the actual TTY to read the password... And another problem is that it not easy to detect when SSH asks for password (it can do it with different strings, which can appear later in the SSH session, etc.)

Comment: Seeing that you're willing to 'write' the password yourself to SSH process, I've updated my answer with the option to use `pexcpet`, which will work for that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SSH uses the SSH_ASKPASS variable only if the process is really detached from TTY (stdin redirecting and setting environment variables is not enough). To detach a process from console it should fork and call os.setsid(). So the first solution I found was:

```
# Detach process
pid = os.fork()
if pid == 0:
    # Ensure that process is detached from TTY
    os.setsid()

    # call ssh from here
else:
    print "Waiting for ssh (pid %d)" % pid
    os.waitpid(pid, 0)    
    print "Done"
```

There is also an elegant way to do this using the subprocess module: in the preexec_fn argument we can pass a Python function that is called in the subprocess before executing the  external command. So the solution for the question is one extra line:

```
env = {'SSH_ASKPASS':'/path/to/myprog', 'DISPLAY':':9999'}
p = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', '-T', '-v', 'user@myhost.com'],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    env=env,
    preexec_fn=os.setsid
)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after.  You're my hero, sir.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that SSH detects your TTY and talks to it directly (as is clearly stated in the man-page). You can try and run ssh without a terminal - the man page suggests it might be necessary to redirect `stdin` to `/dev/null` for ssh to think it has no terminal.

You can also use [pexcept](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/) for this, it's known to work with SSH - example [usage](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/346/python-how-to-access-ssh-with-pexpect/).

The **Right Way** (TM) to do what you're trying to do is either:

1. Use a library specifically for using SSH in python (for example [twisted conch](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedConch) or [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/))
2. Use public and private keys so that passwords will not be necessary

Comment: As you can see in the code, I _am_ redirecting the standard input, and I send no data to it, so it is quite the same as I redirected stdin to /dev/null. Or am I wrong?

I am quite sure that this problem can be solved without using a full ssh implementation: for example, git-gui (written in tcl/tk) can be run from terminal. It runs ssh in the background, and asks for password with its own program (git-gui--askpass).

Comment: I also tried to close stdin immediately after calling Popen to ensure that the code emulates the /dev/null behavior. With no success :(

Comment: I agree that PKI would be much simpler, but: 1. I cannot force all of my users to use public key-based authentication, 2. If the private key is password-protected I still need some password dialog support... (and no, it's not sure that every user has already added the key to its ssh-agent before starting my program...)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a quick and dirty way of doing it for your own personal usage, you could enable passwordless login between these two machines by doing this in your terminal:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa # generate a keypair (if you haven't done this already)
ssh-copy-id user@other_machine # copy your public key to the other machine
```

Then you can get ssh commands to go through (subprocess can't seem to accept ssh commands directly) by creating a script (remember to mark it executable, e.g. `chmod 755 my_script.sh` ) with the things you want, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh user@other_machine ls
```

and call it from your program:

```
import subprocess
response = subprocess.call("./my_script.sh")
print(response)
```

For production-use of apps that need to be deployed on other people's machines I'd go with abyx's approach of using an SSH library. Much simpler than messing with some environment variables.