# Subprocess input shows password

Tags: python, passwords, subprocess

I'm using Python subprocess to run a command on a remote server:

```
p=subprocess.Popen('ssh blah@foo.com "sudo do_something"', shell=True)
```

When I type the password, it appears on the screen - as opposed to running this from the shell, where the password is hidden.

Is there a way to disable this input echo?

Comment: you may want to consult to this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787288/how-to-call-ssh-by-subprocess-module-so-that-it-uses-ssh-askpass-variable

Comment: [`fabric`](http://fabfile.org) might be useful to run a command on a remote server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to consider using pexpect if you have to type something that should be automated: http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect
This way you can ask your user in advance for the password (using the getpass module), and then let your script "type" the password virtually.

There are a couple of well written examples on the website mentioned above describing how to do what you need.